# Elementary Number Theory help

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I missed the day we covered this in class and we have no textbook, so I'd like to know any theorem names and/or formulas used to solve the problem *Prove that if $a$ is an integer then $(a^2+3a+1)^2-1$ is divisible by $24$.*

Comment: If you know modular arithmetic, this is very easy. Note that a number is divisible by 24 iff it is divisible by 3 and by 8.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** You need to show that
$$
(a^2+3a+1)^2-1,
$$
is divisible by $3$ and $8$.

Observe that
$$
(a^2+3a+1)^2-1=(a^2+3a)(a^2+3a+2)=a(a+3)(a+1)(a+2)
$$

So you have the product of four consecutive numbers. At one of them is divisible by $3$, and two of them by two, and if fact of the last two is divided by four.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that you can rewrite
$$
(a^2+3a+1)^2-1 = a(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)
$$
so in particular, one of the terms is a multiple of $4$, one is a multiple of $3$, and one is a multiple of $2$; you get that it must be divisible by $2\cdot 3\cdot 4=24$.

Answer (score 1):

Split $24$ as $24 = 8 \cdot 3$ and prove it separately, it's much simplier. First work with 8.

Note that the first term is always and odd number (WHY?) and we know that $x^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$, where $x$ is odd number, hence the proof.

For 3 it's simplier. First prove that the first term is never a multiple of 3. Assume the contrary then we have:

$$a^2 + 3a + 1 \equiv a^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

But we know that $-1$ isn't quadratic residue modulo 3. So $a^2 + 3a + 1 \equiv 1,2 \pmod 3$. Square both sides and we have: $(a^2 + 3a + 1) - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

We proved that the expression is divisible by $3$ and $8$ and because they are coprime numbers it follows that is also diivsible by their product, i.e. $24$. Hence the proof

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Note $\  n = \color{#c00}{a^2}\!+\!3a \color{#0a0}{+ 1}= \overbrace{a(a\!+\!1)}^{\rm even}+2a\!+\!1 =$  odd.  $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 8\!:\  n^2\equiv$ odd$^2$ $\equiv \{\pm1,\pm3\}^2\equiv 1\,$

$\,{\rm mod}\ 3\!:\,\ n^2 \equiv(\color{#c00}{\{0,\pm1\}^2}\!\color{#0a0}{+1})^2\! \equiv  \{1,2\}^2\equiv 1.\,$  Hence, combining, $\,\ 3,8\mid n^2\!-1\,\Rightarrow\, 24\mid n^2\! -1$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally $(n,m)=1\,\Rightarrow\, n^{\lambda(m)}\equiv 1\pmod m$ where $\lambda(m)$ is the [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). In your case $\ \lambda(3\cdot 8)= {\rm lcm}(\lambda(3),\lambda(8)) = {\rm lcm}(2,2) = 2,\,$ so $\,\,n^2\equiv 1\pmod{24},\,$ when $(n,24)=1,\,$ i.e. for odd $\,n\,$ coprime to $3$.